# How to avoid multiple horizontal scrollbar in the code cell output of Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: java, css, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing Java code on Jupyter Notebooks to print out a table with long rows. To avoid wrapping long rows, I customized Jupyter css as:

```
pre {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

So I successful print out the whole table, but the problem is after an amount of rows, a scrollbar is added? I want to keep just the last scrollbar and remove others. Anybody can help me?[image]

Comment: can you add the html for the table?

Comment: no, i use Java, so i'm drawing the table with characters like '║' : '│. Actually the table is text, not a HTML table.

Comment: I'm thinking more of the output, `table > thead > tr > th` and `table > tbody > tr > td > pre`, does your row have one cell with the pre in it? And how does the rest of the css look for the table?

Comment: By inspecting the output field by Firefox, i can see that the output cell is wrapped by a <div class="output">, in which we have two pairs of <pre>...</pre> tags. When the rows number is bigger, there will be more <pre>...</pre> pairs added. I guess that the browser creates a scrollbar for each <pre> pair.

Comment: so you are not using a table then? If you give me how you structure it this is gone be easy to help you with.

Comment: I'm writing Java code on Juypter Notebooks, it does not support Java much. So i draw the table manually with some code likes: 
for (int col = 0; col < this.dataRow.length; col++) {
            output.append(col == 0 ? '║' : '│');
            output.append(String.format(" %1$-" + this.columnWidths[col] + "s ", this.dataRow[col]));
        }
        output.append("║\n");
actually this is text, not a HTML table.

Comment: As the text is long, and i don't want it wrapping the lines automatically, i change the <pre> tag of css as above, after that i can get scrollbars for long text, but not just 1 scrollbar added as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @Dejan.S for your help, I summarize the answer here in case anybody will need it. We need to customize the custom.css of Jupyter Notebooks as:

```
pre {
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.output {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.output_subarea {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap all the `<div class="output">..</div>` then you can solve it like this. You can remove the color and paddings.

```css
.output {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;

  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.output > pre {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;

  background-color: deepskyblue;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="output">
  <pre>value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | </pre>
  <pre>value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: The output field has not <div class="table"></div>. It starts from <div class="output"></div>. Table above is what i print out by Java code as mentioned by string including '║' : '│.

Comment: When your output from running a code cell is big enough (many lines), Jupyter Notebooks will split the output to many <pre></pre> tags. And with each pair that contains long lines, it will create one separate scrollbar.

Comment: Thank @Dejan.S, it works partially. One big scrollbar was added to the whole output cell, two previous scrollbars still exist but unscrollable. It is not that good, but acceptable, thank you.

Comment: @TruongToDinh you would have to remove your css for the pre.

Comment: your css "output > pre" has no effect with the long rows so i removed it. Actually the "white-space: pre" i wrote in the question keeps the long rows not be wrapped. I added "overflow: hidden;" bellow "white-space: pre" together with your .output {} and two inner scrollbars completly disappeared. Almost done except an empty space at the position of two inner scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>pre { white-space: pre !important; }</style>"))
```

Just put it somewhere at the start of your notebook